# Powershell command to get "clock cycle" in windows

Tags: powershell

Is there any command to get the "clock cycle" in ghz using powershell command ? I can get the maxspeed using below command.

```
$maxClockSpeed = (get-wmiobject Win32_Processor | select-object -first 1).MaxClockSpeed
```

Is it the same ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is the same: [What is a clock cycle and clock speed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43651954/what-is-a-clock-cycle-and-clock-speed)

> Clock Cycle is the speed of a computer processor or CPU, is
>   determined by the clock cycle, which is the amount of time between two
>   pulses of an oscillator. Generally speaking, the higher number of
>   pulses per second, the faster the computer processor will be able to
>   process information.

You can retrieve the current `CurrentClockSpeed` the same way you did for `MaxClockSpeed`.

```
$strComputer = "." 
$colItems = Get-WmiObject -class "Win32_Processor" -namespace "root/CIMV2" -computername $strComputer 

foreach ($objItem in $colItems) { 
    Write-Host 
    Write-Host "CPU ID: " -foregroundcolor yellow -NoNewLine 
    Write-Host $objItem.DeviceID -foregroundcolor white 
    Write-Host "CPU Model: " -foregroundcolor yellow -NoNewLine 
    Write-Host $objItem.Name -foregroundcolor white 
    Write-Host "CPU Cores: " -foregroundcolor yellow -NoNewLine 
    Write-Host $objItem.NumberOfCores -foregroundcolor white 
    Write-Host "CPU Max Speed: " -foregroundcolor yellow -NoNewLine 
    Write-Host $objItem.CurrentClockSpeed 
    Write-Host "CPU Current Speed: " -foregroundcolor yellow -NoNewLine 
    Write-Host $objItem.MaxClockSpeed 
    Write-Host "CPU Status: " -foregroundcolor yellow -NoNewLine 
    Write-Host $objItem. the tatus 
    Write-Host 
}
```

The [Win32_Processor class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394373(v=vs.85).aspx) shows maximum speed and the current speed of the processor in MHz.

Comment: Thanks buddy, but what is the unit for it , when I ran it shows as below.
CPU ID: CPU0
CPU Model: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5300U CPU @ 2.30GHz
CPU Cores: 2
CPU Max Speed: 2277
CPU Current Speed: 2301
CPU Status: OK

Is it Ghz ?